# Large File Size When Converting Bitmap to PDF

Tags: android, pdf, bitmap, kotlin

I'm converting my bitmap files to PDF but when I do so, I noticed that the file size increased a lot. In the sample below, it became 8MB from 3 MB. Any suggestions on what's wrong with my code? It seems to be a straightforward conversion to me.

Thanks!

**Code**

```
                   Timber.d("Creating PDF")

                    val document = PdfDocument()

                    receipt.images.forEachIndexed { index, file ->

                        Timber.d("Picture #$index: ${file.absolutePath}")
                        Timber.d("Filesize: ${file.length() / 1000000}MB")
                        Timber.d("Adding picture to PDF ")

                        val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
                        Timber.d("Decoded bitmap size: ${originalBitmap.byteCount / 1000000}MB")

                        val pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(originalBitmap.width, originalBitmap.height, 1).create()
                        val page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
                        val canvas = page.canvas

                        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
                        document.finishPage(page)
                    }


                    val file = File(cacheDir, "${receipt.name}.pdf")
                    Timber.d("Writing PDF to ${file.absolutePath}")
                    document.writeTo(FileOutputStream(file))
                    Timber.d("PDF file size: ${file.length() / 1000000}MB")

                    Timber.d("Closing PDF")
                    document.close()
```

**Logcat**

```
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Creating PDF
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Picture #0: /data/user/0/com.example.debug/files/2538cb35-d037-4cc0-9f13-2ae98c6d2493
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Filesize: 3MB
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Adding picture to PDF 
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Decoded bitmap size: 31MB
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Writing PDF to /data/user/0/com.example.debug/cache/File 20170907_154650.pdf
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: PDF file size: 8MB
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Closing PDF
D/ListFilesActivity$sh: Sharing PDF
```

Comment: No. The bitmap was 31 MB. And reduced to 8 MB pdf. You did not tell with what kind of image file you started. JPG?

Comment: @greenapps The 31mb is the allocated bitmap size coming from the decoded bitmap (`originalBitmap.byteCount()`). The actual file size is 3MB from `file.length()`

It's saved as JPEG.

Comment: Indeed. So all is pretty normal. You save 31 MB to a pdf maker. Then you end up with 8MB pdf. Any questions?